# Selecting the element with this

Tags: jquery, html

I recently started study jQuery and developing a site, i have two dropbox elements with dropbox class.

```
<a href="#" class="dropbox">+</a>
<a href="#" class="dropbox">+</a>
```

I want the one that clicked slide down, but when i use the "this" selector the slide down doesn't work, can anyone help me explain why?

```
//slideDown() Method
$(".dropbox").click(function(){
    $("this").hide().slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is this:

```
$(".dropbox").click(function(){
    $(this).hide().slideDown();
//    ^---^----------------------- no quotes
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rpfp9qg8/)

Comment: Thanks, i just started using jQuery i thought all the elements are quoted.

Comment: Some elements aren't quoted - more examples: $(window), $(document).